# Uppercase and lower case characters in lua

Tags: lua

```
    if string.find(reply.result_msg, "deleted") or string.find(reply.result_msg, "Deleted") then
    ---
    end
```

can I force it to work faster? Speed is important for me. I dont't want to check twice.

Comment: faster of course

Comment: Convert the msg to lowercase, then run just the second find. You can make an entire string lowercase by calling `string:lower()`.

Comment: @ktb Which will unfortunately also match `dElEtEd`.

Comment: @ktb Also "don't answer questions in comments".

Comment: @user202729 If it was a perfect answer I would have. But it's not an answer.

Comment: @ktb It suffices as an answer... just wrong.

Comment: @user202729 I think you'll find it's usually the questions that are wrong, not the answers.

Comment: `if string.find(reply.result_msg, "eleted", 1, true) then`

Comment: @ktb "Wrong" as in it doesn't do what the question asks for.

Answer (score 3):

You can rewrite your code like this:

```lua
if string.find(reply.result_msg, "[dD]eleted") then
   ---
end
```

That works because

> [`string.find` looks] for the first match of pattern (see §6.4.1) in the string s. [...]
>   
> <sub>Source: [Lua 5.3 Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.find)</sub>

And `[dD]eleted` is a pattern which allows a lower and uppercase letter in the first position.